# Why does God forbid Aaron's descendants with "defects" from offering food?

Tags: old-testament, priesthood, leviticus, offering

**Leviticus 21:16-23**

> 16 The Lord said to Moses, 17 “Say to Aaron: ‘For the generations to
>   come none of your descendants who has a defect may come near to offer
>   the food of his God. 18 No man who has any defect may come near: no
>   man who is blind or lame, disfigured or deformed; 19 no man with a
>   crippled foot or hand, 20 or who is a hunchback or a dwarf, or who has
>   any eye defect, or who has festering or running sores or damaged
>   testicles. 21 No descendant of Aaron the priest who has any defect is
>   to come near to present the food offerings to the Lord. He has a
>   defect; he must not come near to offer the food of his God. 22 He may
>   eat the most holy food of his God, as well as the holy food; 23 yet
>   because of his defect, he must not go near the curtain or approach the
>   altar, and so desecrate my sanctuary. I am the Lord, who makes them
>   holy.’”

Why would a loving God, who loves all people equally, seemingly discriminate against Aaron's descendants with these "defects"?

Comment: It's pretty clear what is being conveyed is that God's holiness is on display here. It demands perfection, and disallowing those that are quite evidently not 'whole' in body is simply a symbol of this demand of perfection.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is just the priests. If you couldn't be a priest, it wasn't the end of the world or anything.

Comment: @series0ne updated my answer, sorry it was half an explanation. hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

From context, we get this command was given to Aaron and his descendants, those ordained for Priesthood. It mentions there these are considered "defects"; an imperfection. It's a symbol of sanctification; God setting apart, and also what is acceptable to God (perfection, purity, holiness). Similar to why [sacrificial lambs are to be without blemish](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus%2012%3A5&version=NKJV). Also why [Jesus had to be without sin to be an acceptable atonement for our sins](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20cor%205%3A21&version=NKJV).